How do I set up a server on PC if my router is not connected to the Internet directly?
For educational purposes I am trying to set up a personal Apache server on a virtual machine on my laptop (the VM runs Ubuntu Server 24.04, the host laptop has Ubuntu Desktop 24.04). The laptop is connected to a Wi-Fi router (TP-Link Archer C20). However, the router itself is not connected to the Internet directly, but rather to my ISP's local network, hence, it does not have a public IP address (to add to confusion, the public IP I have is dynamic). Can I make the server running on my laptop public, and if yes, how do I do that?


However, the router itself is not connected to the Internet directly, but rather to my ISP's local network

The ISP's local network is part of the Internet, and even if you directly had a public IP address, you'd still be connected to the ISP's network first.
You could say that the lack of public addressing is what makes the connection kind of "local" in a sense – rather than being the result of the connection being local – because the physical and logical topology would be more or less the same either way.

hence, it does not have a public IP address (to add to confusion, the public IP I have is dynamic).

You need a public IP address somewhere.
The most direct method is to call your ISP and see if you can order a dedicated public IP address (or "static IP address" as many ISPs call it – implies that it'll have all properties necessary for receiving inbound connections, even if they're not explicitly mentioned in the name of the service).
(Side note: If your ISP cannot provide a public IPv4 address, it's still possible that they will provide IPv6 – sure, it won't help you at all if you want to receive IPv4-only visitors, but increasingly more ISPs can do IPv6, so it's still worth trying out for educational purposes.)
If the ISP cannot provide a dedicated IPv4 address, your only other option is to set up a relay through some other ISP which can – such as:

a commercial VPN service that offers dedicated IP addresses for server hosting (some do),

or a custom VPN through a cheap VPS server rented from some hosting company (all you need is regular OpenVPN or WireGuard or something similar),

or a TCP tunnel through said cheap VPS (using SSH's built-in "remote forward" feature that can relay arbitrary inbound connections through an outbound SSH connection),

or even one of those free HTTP-only relay services (like cloudflare or ngrok).


Once your personal server establishes the initial VPN/tunnel connection to the relay host, it can receive connections through the relay for as long as the tunnel is up. When using a VPN (options 1 or 2), search for older posts talking about "policy routing" for the special configuration necessary.
